# div leaving space when positioned absolute in td

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand position absolute. I have the below code snippet

```css
div#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div1">
        This is a heading with an absolute position
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am getting some extra white space in the top due to positioning absolute. 
When I specify **`top:0px`**, it is working fine.

Can someone please explain why some space is left behind when using only left and right positioning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` for table cells is `baseline`. The effect of this can be seen in the first `<table>` below.

This causes the table contents, text or `<div>`, to be placed around the vertical center.

If you want to move the `<div>` to the top, `vertical-align: top;` will do the trick. Or a `top: 0;`.

```css
div#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Some text
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="div1">This is a heading with an absolute position</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the **`padding`** also. It will remove the rest of the space.

Comment: @weBer there is no padding and it's not about **removing spaces** but why we have spaces

Comment: @TemaniAfif if u use `vertical-align: top;` to the `<td>` there still be a little space above the `div` that's why bro.

Comment: @weBer read again the answer :) and then tell me where do you see **padding**

Comment: @TemaniAfif please check this link - https://drive.google.com/a/autozonecentre.com/file/d/1gKmgRvAc6ngM7k5WIYZuOUnZqOmQOl53/view?usp=drivesdk , if I took it in a wrong way my bad. ;)

Comment: @weBer this *padding* is simply the default behavior of using table :) and still doesn't understand why you want to remove it ... this is not the purpose of the question ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif if we use the `top:0px` to the div it will not be there, that's why I suggested it.:) and in the left and right there will be no space that way.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you put a `<div>` into a `<td>` tag.

Base vertical position of a table cell is middle.

See example below:

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;   
}

div#absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

div#absolute-top0 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                This is a div <b>without</b> an absolute position.
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="absolute">
                This is a div <b>with</b> an absolute position.
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="absolute-top0">
                This is a div <b>with</b> an absolute position and top: 0.
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @weBer there is no padding and it's not about **removing spaces** but why we have spaces

Answer (score -1):

That's because you have given **the td position relative here**. Change that also in absolute. you'll have no space left there.

Here's the => **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/sqwyvmpx/1/)**

```
div#div1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 0;
   right:0;
   height:100px;
   border: 1px solid green;
   background-color:green;
   width:100%;   
}
td {
   position:absolute;
   background:red;
   height:18px;
   width:100%;    
}
table {
   width:100%;
}

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div id="div1">This is a heading with an absolute position</div>
 </td>
</tr>
```